# C# ASP.NET MVC Table rows as form values FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I'm stuck with getting values out of the FormCollection in my controller. The problem is that my form is a table.

```
   <% using (Html.BeginForm("PasOverlappendeAfwezighedenAan", "Afwezigheid")) {%>        
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            datumVan
        </th>
        <th>
            datumTot
        </th>

        <th>
            beginUur
        </th>
        <th>
            eindUur
        </th>
       <th>
            reden
        </th>
    </tr>

       <% foreach (var item in Model.Afwezigheden)
          { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="datumVan" id="datumVan" value="<%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.datumVan) %>" />  
        </td>
        <td>
              <input type="text" name="datumTot" id="Text1" value="<%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.datumTot) %>" />  
        </td>

        <td>
           <input type="text" name="beginUur" id="Text2" value="<%: item.beginUur %>" />  
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" name="eindUur" id="Text3" value="<%: item.eindUur %>" />  
        </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" name="reden" id="Text4" value="<%: item.reden %>" />  
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
<% } %>
```

So the Controller should turn each row from the table into an object.

```
public ActionResult PasOverlappendeAfwezighedenAan(FormCollection fc, Student stud){

}
```

But how would I get a row or the data for one row out of the FormCollection?

Thanks in advance,
Me

ps: sorry for the dutch names in the codes

Answer (score 0):

sure we can use the form colleciton like:

```
public ActionResult Test2(FormCollection postback)
{
    var i = postback["beginUur"];
    var j = postback["eindUur"];

    return View();
}
```

then the value of i will be a string like: "20,40,60" if our post form has 3 fields(or called [input text]) is named "beginUur".. and we can use

```
string [] beginUurResult = i.Split(',');
```

to get the string array of each beginUur value

--

or each field be a single List like:

```
public ActionResult PasOverlappendeAfwezighedenAan(List<string> datumVan, List<string> datumTot){

}
```

Comment: Would there be no possible way in using the FormCollection?

Comment: @Sir Troll: Sure~ please see my new post :)

Comment: @Sir Troll: Is the answer can help you?